# what's the exact mean of "thread creation and termination" about critical execution point in c# specification

Tags: c#, volatile

in 3.10 of c# specification, following is:

The critical execution points at which the order of these side effects must be preserved are references to volatile fields (§10.5.3), lock statements (§8.12), and **thread creation and termination**.

question is:the thread creation mean "new Thread();" or "th.start()"?

by my knowledge, I think it at least contains "th.start()".